# How to start Teamviewer on boot up?

Tags: boot

How can I autostart Teamviewer on my Raspberry Pi upon system boot up?

Comment: What distro and version are you running? How did you install it? Are you sure it does not start upon reboot? If so how do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

@/usr/share/applications/com.teamviewer.TeamViewer-Host.desktop